# Update the same field in multiple work items through TFS API or powershell script

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I know we could bulk update TFS work items with Excel.

However, this time I want to integrate this in my build process. Do it either with TFS API or power shell script. We are working on TFS2017/VS2017

I look forward to any suggestions from your guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this through a powershell script based on TFS client API.

PowerShell lets you load any .Net assembly by using the **Add-Type** cmdlet.

> You can then use the classes defined in that assembly inside your
>   PowerShell session. This opens up a wide range of possibilities, one
>   of them being that you can use the TFS API from PowerShell.

- *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client*
- *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client*

After the TFS assemblies have been loaded, we can get a reference to the TPC:

```
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsUri)
```

And then the $tfs object can be used to access the required services (the work item store in this case):

```
$workItemStore = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
```

For the other things and more detail, you could  find the entire script on *KeesV's* GitHub: [TfsBulkUpdateWi.ps1](https://github.com/KeesV/RealALMScripts/blob/master/TFS/TfsBulkUpdateWi.ps1)

Another blog for your reference: [How to batch update multiple work items in TFS by PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-batch-update-149046f5)